# Let $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfy $f(x) \le x$ and $f(x+y) \le f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$. Show that $f(x)=x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math, functional-equations, functional-inequalities

> Let $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfy $$f(x) \le x$$ and $$f(x+y) \le f(x)+f(y)$$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$. Show that $f(x)=x$.

I already know that $f(0) = 0$ but I don’t know how to do next. Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: Which contest is it from please ?

Comment: It’s just a problem in the book written about contest math. Would you like me to remove the tag?

Comment: No, no need to remove the tag. Which book ?

Comment: It’s in Thai. It is about the problems that could be TSTST in Thailand.

Comment: After *Let*, there is no need to inflect the verb.  For example, "Let it ***go***" as oppose to "Let it go*es*."  Here is another example, "He lets her ***take*** his car" as oppose to "He lets her take*s* his car."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}$ satisfy

(a) $f(x)\leq x$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and

(b) $f(x+y)\leq f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

From (b), with $x,y:=0$, we get $f(0)\geq 0$.  However, by (a), we conclude that $f(0)=0$.

Now, using (a), we have $f(-x)\leq -x$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Now, plug in $y:=-x$ in (b) to get
$$0=f(0)=f\big(x+(-x)\big)\leq f(x)+f(-x)\leq x+(-x)=0\,.$$
This implies $f(x)+f(-x)=0$ (and in fact, at this point, it already follows that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$).  Hence, $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Using (a), we have
$$-f(x)=f(-x)\leq -x\,,$$
or
$$f(x)\geq x$$
for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  By (a), we see that $f(x)=x$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

By pluging in $a$ and $-a$:

$\forall a\in \mathbb{R}: f(a)+f(-a)\ge f(0) = 0$

from what was given, $f(a) \le a,f(-a) \le-a$

So: $f(a)-a \ge f(a)+f(-a) \ge 0 \to f(a) \ge a$ (True because $-a \ge f(-a)$     )

We have that $f(a) \le a $

and also that $f(a) \ge a$

So $f(a)=a$

Answer (score 2):

From the second inequality, $f(x+h)\leq f(x)+f(h)$ so that,
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\leq \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(x)+f(h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(h)}{h}$$
But from the first inequality in the question, $f(h)/h\leq 1$ so that, $$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\leq \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(h)}{h}\leq 1$$
Similarly, $$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}\geq \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(x)-(f(x)+f(-h))}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(-h)}{-h}$$ 
But $f(-h)/(-h)\geq 1$ (inequality reverses when dividing by a negative number and $-h<0$ since $h>0$). Thus we get, 
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}\geq \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(-h)}{-h}\geq 1$$

On the other hand, for $h>0$,
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{f(x+h)-f((x+h)+(-h))}{h}\geq \frac{f(-h)}{-h}\geq 1$$
and
$$\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}=\frac{f((x-h)+h)-f(x-h)}{h}\leq \frac{f(h)}{h}\leq 1$$

Therefore $f'(x)$ exists and $f'(x)=1$ (particularly, the fact that limit of a function strictly dominated by another function is less than or equal to limit of the other function is used).

This means that $f(x)=x+c$, where the integration constant $c=0$ because $f(0)=0$.

Thanks to Batominovski for supplying the proof for differentiability of this function.

Comment: This would be a nice solution if $f$ is assumed to be differentiable, but there isn't such an assumption.  (It is up to you, but I think you should keep this answer, rather than deleting it.  It might teach the OP a new trick.)

Comment: @Batominovski Ah right! I will edit my answer to include the assumption that the function is differentiable, but ya now my answer won't matter much. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: After a bit of thinking, I think your solution can be modified, so that you don't have to assume differentiability.  You have proven that $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\leq 1$$ and $$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}\geq 1\,.$$

On the other hand, for $h>0$,
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{f(x+h)-f\big((x+h)+(-h)\big)}{h}\geq \frac{-f(-h)}{h}=\frac{f(-h)}{-h}\geq 1$$
and
$$\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}=\frac{f\big((x-h)+h\big)-f(x-h)}{h}\leq \frac{f(h)}{h}\leq 1\,.$$
Therefore, $f'(x)$ exists, and it is equal to $1$.

Comment: @Batominovski That's really nice! I should have thought in this direction.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if you use my comment to improve your answer, so the differentiability assumption can be removed from your answer.

Comment: I referred to your comment since I wasn't sure if I could use your proof. Now that you have said this, I will include this in my answer.